# DESCryptor, работа с разными типами файлами

Tags: c#, криптография

Делал на С# программу которая должна делать копию папки с файлами разного типа, и попутно их шифровать.
Использовал для шифрования файла класс DESCryptor. Вот код

```
private void cryptFile(string key,string load,string save)
{
    FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(load,
                 FileMode.Open,
                 FileAccess.Read);

    FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(save,
       FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
       FileAccess.Write);
    DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
    CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted,
       desencrypt,
       CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length];
    fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
    cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
    cryptostream.Close();
    fsInput.Close();
    fsEncrypted.Close();
}


private void decryptFile(string key,string load,string save)
{
    DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    DES.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
    FileStream fsread = new FileStream(load,
       FileMode.Open,
       FileAccess.Read);
    ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();
    CryptoStream cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(fsread,
       desdecrypt,
       CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    StreamWriter fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter(save);
    fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd());
    fsDecrypted.Flush();
    fsDecrypted.Close();
}
```

Возникла проблема, программа нормально работает только с файлами .тхт.
А при работе с файлами другого расширения, например .xml, .java и тд. их содержимое полностью не совпадает с исходным, иногда выскакивает ошибка Baddata.
В общем, расшифровать их не получается.

Как заставить его работать с разными типами файлов, или есть ли альтернативный код который позволит справится с данной проблемой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы зачем-то конвертируете файл в строчку перед записью на диск (прогоняете его через `StreamWriter`/`StreamWriter`/`ReadToEnd` - это все работа с данными как со строками). Exe мало похож на строчку, поэтому данные немного портятся в процессе. Вместо этого надо писать прямо в файл. И вообще поменьше работать с буферами напрямую:

```
private void cryptFile(string key, string load, string save)
{
    using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(load))
    {
        using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(save))
        {
            DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
            using (CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(outputStream,
                desencrypt,
                CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {

                inputStream.CopyTo(cryptostream);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void decryptFile(string key, string load, string save)
{
    DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    DES.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
    using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(load))
    {
        ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();
        CryptoStream cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(inputStream,
           desdecrypt,
           CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(save))
        {
            cryptostreamDecr.CopyTo(outputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Кстати, все криптоалгоритмы работают с данными как с наборами блоков, так что будьте готовы к тому, что файл на выходе станет чуть длиннее. Чтобы получить точно те же данные - нужно где-то (например, в начале зашифрованного файла) сохранять длину, и при расшифровке обрезать результат. Хотя может быть есть более красивые способы решения этой проблемы.